# PowerPoint 2013 missing "Paste Special" context menu

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

This is the strangest thing. I have googled for answers but can't seem to find ones that apply.

All I want to do is select a portion of an Excel file and paste/link it into a PowerPoint presentation, so that if the Excel file is updated, the corresponding PowerPoint presentation reflects the updates made to the Excel spreadsheet.

According to everything I've read, I should be seeing a 'Paste Special' context menu in PowerPoint, that would allow me to paste the Excel snippet as an object.

However, it does not show up:

[image: Screenshot of PowerPoint 2013 Context Menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is hiding in the "Home" ribbon as shown below. You need to click on the down arrow in the bottom portion of the icon.

You will then need to paste link from the past special menu..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Why on earth did they not put this in the right-click context menu? I would have never looked on the ribbon.